# What's the longest concertina word you can find?

Tags: wordplay

What's a concertina word?

A concertina word, word Z, is a word in English which can be formed from splicing together two other English words, word X and word Y, such that the letters of word X form the odd numbered letters of word Z, and word Y, the even ones.

It might be simplest to explain with a simple example:

The words FRIENDS is a concertina word because it can be formed from the words:

```
    1234567
    F I N S
and  R E D
```

While the prize ('what prize' I hear you ask) goes to the longest word, bonus points ('what bonus points') are on offer for interesting answers - for instance, where words x, y, and z make a plausible phrase, or where the subwords resonate with the meaning of the superword.

Rosie F advises that this sort of construction is actually called an alternade q.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternade (although I like my term better).

Comment: This sounds like an interesting candidate for code golf!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because without defining "word" it turns into an ill-defined, open-ended puzzle (and [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) as of May 2019)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A computer search finds

> [UNPOROUSNESS](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/porousness) formed from [UPRUNS](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/uprun) and [NOOSES](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/noose)

though it's not a great word. (A web search does find at least one place -- a technical article -- in which it is used.)

The computer search, starting with a big wordlist, went like this:

```
words = set(open(___filename of wordlist___).read().split())
def is_concertina(w): return w[::2] in words and w[1::2] in words
good = {w for w in words if is_concertina(w)}
m = max(len(w) for w in good)
list((w,w[::2],w[1::2]) for w in good if len(w)==m)
```

which returns the example above and no others. So if you don't like the long word there, we'd better look at shorter ones; here are the two that were found with the length reduced by 1:

> TRIENNIALLY from TINILY and RENAL
>  CURTAINLESS from CRANES and UTILS

Comment: That's a great one (maybe the greatest?). Care to explain your method? (I really don't understand how you managed to complete this task within a minute of my asking ;-) )

Comment: I'll put some details into the answer.

Comment: Done; I also give a couple of shorter examples (there are no others of equal length with my wordlist), at least one of which is I think perfectly convincing in that no one could question whether any of the things it uses is a "real" word.

Comment: unporousness: The lack of pores.

Comment: *Curtainless* isn't in [SCOWL](http://app.aspell.net/create) with all options on, meaning you've got an even bigger wordlist. *Unporousness* is though.

Comment: Well found. For the benefit of researchers present and future, such a word is called an alternade.

Comment: What are "upruns"?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan what word list are you using?

Comment: My computer search of SCOWL also found `carpetweeds`, `neesberries`, and `spallations` in the 11 character word category.

Comment: N. Virgo's question was answered in a comment that's since been deleted by its author. I'm pretty sure this is because said author deleted _all_ their comments rather than because they repudiated this one in particular, so here it is again: 'Uprun is a verb (meaning "run up"), not a noun. See for example William Cowper's Iliad XVIII 541–3 "A son ... like a luxuriant plant / Upran to manhood".'

Answer (score 12):

Some for the fun/phrase category:

> Peewee's ewe pees
>  Clips Calliope's aloe
>  Pro-parrot art
>  Lord Bloodred bode
>  Sauteed, ate, sued
>  Ones countess cuts
>  Sand tie stained
>  Weirdoes: wide eros

Comment: I love sauteed, ate, sued. A sand stained tie is also a nice idea.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps a nod to a recent conspiracy theory (of at least one individual)

> If you combine **POLLS** and **EPEES** you get **PEOPLELESS**

Not as long as any of Gareth McCaughan's but obtained with a similar method.

Comment: Used carelessly enough, I suppose epees can produce peopleless polls.

Answer (score 4):

Going for the bonus, putting the long word first or last which seems in keeping with the spirit of the question (though it doesn't help much in the middle):

> ```
>     C L A S S
>      O L P E
>     COLLAPSES
> ```

For 9 is the longest *plausible* sentence I can find with the long word first or last.  According to Wiktionary an *olpe* is *Originally, a leather flask or vessel for oils or liquids; afterward, an earthenware vase or pitcher without a spout*

For common words:

> ```
>     S O L D
>      P I E
>     SPOILED
> ```

For a mere 7.

Comment: This used Gareth McCaughan's [approach](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/44633/8765) (and indeed a modified version of his code).

Comment: I particularly like sold pie spoiled

Comment: @Strawberry I nearly answered with just that but managed to extract a sentence from a longer combination at the last minute